# Installing WSL Ubuntu 20.04 Distribution - WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80041002

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I try to get Docker running on Windows 10 Home 10.0.19043 Build 19043 but for that I need a running WSL environment with a distribution on it. So I installed Ubuntu 20.04. from the Windows Store. But when I start the Ubuntu 20.04 application, I get this output in the terminal:

**WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80041002**

This issue seems to be well known and I tried all of the answers in all of these threads:

- [Changing the LxssManager to automatic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error/dd28f58e-869a-4a33-8b7f-95695371cb0d?auth=1)
- [Restarting the LxssManager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142359/error-0x80080005-server-execution-failed-while-installing-ubuntu-on-windows) (
  sc query LxssManager returns nothing)
- [Sudo apt-upgrade](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wslregisterdistribution-failed-0x80041002) (Doesn't work because after typing "bash" the terminal tells me there is no distribution installed)
- [Check and Uncheck Windows Subsystem for Linux + Restart](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error/dd28f58e-869a-4a33-8b7f-95695371cb0d?auth=1)
- [Starting the Ubuntu 20.04 application manually to finish installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794261/wsl-issue-windows-subystem-for-linux-has-no-installed-distributions)

I have no idea what to do now. Is WSL actually broken beyond fixing it as end user?

Edit: I use a Comodo Firewall

Comment: What security software do you have installed instead replying with a comment be sure to edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound As demanded, I added the firewall provider (Comodo Firewall)

Comment: Try temporarily disabling it and/or uninstalling it. Sadly, my research for Jan 17 don't the subject, was lost when I closed my tabs.  I believe the software that had a bug, and that introduced this error and was later patched, was Comodo but I can't be certain.

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled all distributions and deactivated the hypervisor service and the wsl in the WIndows Features. I deactivated Comodo, restarted, activated the Hypervisor service and WSL, installed Ubuntu 20.04 and started the Ubuntu 20.04 application. Still the same error. And typing in "bash" into the Powershell tells me that I have no installed distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The key is not only to deactivate Comodo. You have to uninstall it.
So follow these steps:

1. Uninstall Comodo + Restart
2. Uninstall all distributions
3. Deactivate Hypervisor and WSL service in Windows Features + Restart
4. Activate Hypervisor and WSL service in Windows Features + Restart
5. If you install the Distribution via Shell, start it as admin
6. Then install it