# Virtualization is enabled in BIOS and Windows 11 but running Ubuntu WSL yields 0x80370102

Tags: virtualization, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Ryzen 2700X on a B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85), I have SMV enabled in BIOS and it shows up in the taskmanager on the CPU tab as `Virtualization: Enabled`.

Yet when I start Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it fails:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
```

What am I missing? I have hyper-v both enabled and disabled, it works neither way.

Here's a list of my currently enabled / disabled Windows features:

[image]

Comment: Install WSL through the Windows Store using the install command instead of enabling the feature within the Optional Windows Feature dialog.

Comment: Yes, my question was going to be how you have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,

Comment: @harrymc through the windows store

Comment: @Ramhound shall I disable the feature first and then install WSL through app store?

Comment: You already did that. Try : Disable the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature, restart Windows, re-enable the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature, restart Windows.

Comment: @k0pernikus - Uninstall everything (Virtual Machine Platform, and Windows Subsystem for Linux), reboot the system, then just run the install command as documented by Microsoft.

Comment: The answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1699814/installing-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-distribution-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-e?rq=1)  question is likely relevant. My advice is to still uninstall everything and install the current supported version of WSL instead of using the legacy version you currently have installed.